# Connect MySQL on AWS via SSH on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to connect MySQL on AWS via SSH on Jupyter Notebook. 
I am able to connect on Terminal with:

```
ssh -L 13306:company.amazonaws.com:3306 user_name -f -N
```

and then,

```
mysql -usupport -h127.0.0.1 --port=13306 -p
```

I'm also able to connect via SequelPro.

However, by using MySQL python libraries, how can I extract data or write query on Jupyter notebook?

I use MacOS Sierra.

Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to find a way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [jupyter kernel](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb_kernel) to write SQL statements, but in order to connect to a AWS MySQL or MariaDB server, you will need to setup ssh port forwarding if ssh is the only way you can access your AWS instance.